# PHP json_decode Not Working

Tags: php, json

Alright, so, I have a game that uploads data in the form of JSON to my site. The JSON resembles this:

```
{
  "PlayerList":[
    {
        "PlayerKills":0,
        "Username":"Player1",
        "TimePlayed":0,
        "Deaths":0
    },
    {
        "PlayerKills":0,
        "Username":"Player1",
        "TimePlayed":0,
        "Deaths":0
    }
  ]
}
```

After confirming that the JSON is indeed correct, and without errors, I began speculating that the problem lie in the PHP. The code I use to get the JSON is:

```
$decodedJSON =  json_decode($entityBody, true, 4);              
var_dump($decodedJSON);
```

With $entitybody being the JSON as a string.

The var_dump here returns NULL, and since I'm stuck using PHP 5.2, I cannot determine what    the problem is using json_last_error.

So if anyone can provide me some info as to where the problem lies, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: seems like working [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fyg-yzb)

Comment: me too got this error when my json data format was wrong(make sure json format is correct with the following link..... even if it seems correct), and i corrected using [JSONLint an json validator](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: You most definitely should not be using PHP 5.2.  It's been EOL'd for years and if you're running it on the public internet then you're wide open to a whole host of security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Check if your data is UTF-8 with a Byte Order Mark. I removed my BOM and my problems went away

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
$entityBody = stripslashes($entityBody);
// this will remove all backslashes which might be the cause of returning NULL

$decodedJSON = json_decode($entityBody, true);
// leave out the depth unless you really need it to be 4.

var_dump($decodedJSON);
```

Documentation:

**`stripslashes`** - http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

**`json_decode`** - http://php.net/json_decode

Answer (score 4):

Don't set the `depth` parameter. Just `json_decode($entityBody,true);` should work.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 5.2 `json_decode` requires 2 parameters not 3. I checked it on PHP 5.2.17 and it shows:

```
Warning: json_decode() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given.
```

If you omit third parameter you will get what you want :)